# rails - active admin - PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a scope in a Model which works perfectly fine when I call it from rails console but when I try to use it in active admin it throws an error

Here is the scope

```
scope :clicked, -> { select('distinct on (email_stats.clicked_url) email_stats.*').order(:clicked_url, :action_performed_at)}
```

Here is the error i get when i try to use it in active admin

> ActionView::Template::Error (PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
>   LINE 1: SELECT  distinct on (email_stats.clicked_url) email_stats.* ...
>                                ^
>   : SELECT  distinct on (email_stats.clicked_url) email_stats.* FROM “email_stats” ORDER BY “email_stats”.“id” desc, “email_stats”.“clicked_url” ASC, “email_stats”.“action_performed_at” ASC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2):

Could anyone please let me know what am i missing here? I have been looking into other posts but none of them seem helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use distinct inside the scope may be problematic. Instead I use:

```
controller do
  def apply_filtering(collection)
    super.distinct
  end
end
```